# What's the VHDL equivalent of __FILE__?

Tags: vhdl

I'd like to prefix files read from a VHDL testbench with the testbench's file name programmatically.

Maybe there are equivalents to something like the __FILE__ (__LINE__, __FUNCTION__, __DATE__, ...) macros from C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VHDL-2008 doesn't have such features but if you use VUnit you can make log calls containing file name and line number. See http://vunit.github.io/python_interface.html?highlight=location#vunit.ui.VUnit.enable_location_preprocessing

The upcoming VHDL-2019 standard defines a function to get the path to the caller which includes the name of the element making the call, file name and line number. The standard also defines functions to get date and time.